# INSERT INTO @TABLE EXEC @query with SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Is it true that SQL Server 2000, you can not insert into a table variable using exec?

I tried this script and got an error message:

> EXECUTE cannot be used as a source when inserting into a table variable.

```
declare @tmp TABLE (code varchar(50), mount money)
DECLARE @q nvarchar(4000)
SET @q = 'SELECT coa_code, amount FROM T_Ledger_detail'

INSERT INTO  @tmp (code, mount)
EXEC sp_executesql (@q)

SELECT * from @tmp
```

If that true, what should I do?

Comment: If it's true, you should `CREATE TEMP TABLE` (I'm sure you can insert into a temp table from EXEC).

Comment: "Is it true?" - [yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260638(v=sql.80).aspx) - "However, table may not be used in the following statements: INSERT INTO table_variable EXEC stored_procedure"

Comment: Ok, i got it,, it's like @Anton Kovalenko said,, i need to create temporary table , not Table variable ... Thx. :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**N.B.** - this question and answer relate to the 2000 version of SQL Server. In later versions, the restriction on `INSERT INTO @table_variable ... EXEC ...` were lifted and so it doesn't apply for those later versions.

---

You'll have to switch to a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (code varchar(50), mount money)
DECLARE @q nvarchar(4000)
SET @q = 'SELECT coa_code, amount FROM T_Ledger_detail'

INSERT INTO  #tmp (code, mount)
EXEC sp_executesql (@q)

SELECT * from #tmp
```

---

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260638(v=sql.80).aspx):

> A table variable behaves like a local variable. It has a well-defined scope, which is the function, stored procedure, or batch in which it is declared.
>
> Within its scope, a table variable may be used like a regular table. It may be applied anywhere a table or table expression is used in SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. However, table may not be used in the following statements:
>
> `INSERT INTO table_variable EXEC stored_procedure`
>
> `SELECT select_list INTO table_variable statements.`

Comment: @Damien, in your example there is no reason to use a Temp Table, you can still use a Table variable even in your example.

Comment: Verified that you can use @tableVariables in 2008+

Comment: @ohmusama - yes, but the question is tagged `2000` and I've linked to the 2000 documentation saying it's not available.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I know, but since google can't figure that out, (as I got here from there), this is a comment for other people like me.

Comment: @ohmusama - okay, I've added an note at the top to (try to) make it clear that this question and answer do just relate to the 2000 version of the product.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I just wanted to leave a comment for others. In no way was your answer wrong or needed changing. That wasn't my objective. But okay.

Answer (score 14):

The documentation is misleading.
I have the following code running in production

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (UserID varchar(100))
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'spSelUserIDList'
/* Will also work
   SET @sql = 'SELECT UserID FROM UserTable'
*/

INSERT INTO @table
EXEC(@sql)

SELECT * FROM @table
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @q nvarchar(4000)
SET @q = 'DECLARE @tmp TABLE (code VARCHAR(50), mount MONEY)
INSERT INTO @tmp
  (
    code,
    mount
  )
SELECT coa_code,
       amount
FROM   T_Ledger_detail

SELECT *
FROM   @tmp'

EXEC sp_executesql @q
```

If you want in dynamic query

Comment: yes , i want the values is from dynamic script.. and i think this is not dynamic..

Comment: So above query will help you

Comment: Yeah this is a static execution.  In order for this to be dynamic you need to have concatenations within the assignment to the `@q` variable.  Nice try but no dice.