# How to get sql server stored procedure result to process in an other stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing the situation where I need to use result of one stored procedure within another stored procedure. My first stored procedure returns a subset of a table and I want to use it in second stored procedure.

The `exec dbo.myprcedure param` returns the result but I need to capture it within another stored procedure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a TABLE VARIABLE in either a `FUNCTION` or a `STORED PROCEDURE` and then use that `TABLE VARIABLE` in your caller Stored Procedure for further processing or to pass on to another Stored Procedure as a TABLE VARIABLE Parameter.

i.e. Create a Function as follows that returns a TABLE VARIABLE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedureThatReturnsATable()
RETURNS  @ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    -- specify columns returned by the proc here
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
.
..
...

--This select returns data 
INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
SELECT ID, Name FROM SOME_TABLES

RETURN

END
```

Then in the parent Stored Procedure, you would execute above stored procedure and populate a TABLE Variable in that parent Stored Procedure as follows.

```
DECLARE @MyParentTableVariable as TABLE (ID INT, Name nvarchar(255))

INSERT INTO @MyParentTableVariable
EXECUTE MyProcedureThatReturnsATable
```

So now, in the parent Stored Procedure, you have the data from the `MyProcedureThatReturnsATable` in a TABLE VARIABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stored procedure you can use view..A view can contain selected data's from a table.First create one view then call view in your stored procedure

or

create a temp table.from temp table you can get data's

Comment: I am using Entity Framework 6 and I don't want to use Views because they make it too slow to dig out data.

Answer (score 0):

Provided it returns just one result set, you can create a temp table then use syntax

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC dbo.myprocedure @param
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623262/8479

But in general it's better to find a different approach, e.g. use [table-valued variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674492/8479) or use a function instead of a proc.

Comment: I could not understand your better approach in last line.
your answer is impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the 1st stored Procedure inside you Secod stored Procedure and use the results there. Something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_2
@param
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

/* Create a Temp Table here say #TempTable*/

INSERT INTO #TempTable
exec dbo.myporcedure @param 

/* Your rest of the code that needs to work with the result set of dbo.myporcedure */

END
```