# SQL Server : EXECUTE error when trying to query with variable statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exec

The task is to scroll through all tables and columns to find the table and column names containig the searched value. The script I use is:

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#temp_sar') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #temp_sar 
go 

CREATE TABLE #temp_table 
( 
     [table_name]  VARCHAR, 
     [column_name] VARCHAR 
) 

DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR 
DECLARE @Column_Name VARCHAR 
DECLARE @Search_Value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '303D9191-E201-4299-809E-FC7B0213F73C') 

DECLARE @CURSOR CURSOR 

SET @CURSOR = CURSOR scroll  FOR 
     (SELECT s.table_name, 
            s.column_name 
      FROM information_schema.columns s 
      WHERE s.data_type = 'uniqueidentifier') 

OPEN @CURSOR 

FETCH next FROM @CURSOR INTO @Table_Name, @Column_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    IF @Search_Value = EXEC ('select distinct' + @Column_Name + 'from' 
                             + @Table_Name + 'where' + @Column_Name + '=' 
                              + @Search_Value) 
        INSERT INTO #temp_table ([table_name], [column_name]) 
        VALUES (@Table_Name, @Column_Name) 

    FETCH next FROM @CURSOR INTO @Table_Name, @Column_Name 
END 

CLOSE @CURSOR 

SELECT * FROM #temp_table;
```

When this is executed, I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'

Please help me make this code work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: You are not ready for this level of complexity. And generally speaking, most any question/task you have has already been addressed so searching the internet should be your first step. This specific task is one of those - [search all columns all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: Sure i'm not Smor, otherwise why would i ask for help... Anyway thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this line...

```
  IF @Search_Value = Exec('select distinct' + @Column_Name + 'from' 
                          + @Table_Name + 'where' + @Column_Name + '=' 
                          + @Search_Value)
```

First, make sure that you have spaces in the necessary places in your sql string...

```
Exec('select distinct ' + @Column_Name + ' from ' 
                        + @Table_Name + ' where ' + @Column_Name + ' = ' 
                        + @Search_Value
)
```

Next, if you execute a `SELECT` statement, the results are a data-set, not a scalar.  This also means that the data-set is also not returned in the same as a function returns a scalar result.

It is possible to use `EXEC @myReturn = spSomethingOrAnother(@param, @anotherParam);` to capture anything sent back with a `RETURN` statement *(At the end of the SP)*, but I don't think that works with Dynamic SQL...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql

Your next option could be to create a table to insert the results in to, then check that table...

[INSERT INTO @TABLE EXEC @query with SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622940/insert-into-table-exec-query-with-sql-server-2000)

```
CREATE TABLE #result (search_value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO 
  #result (
    search_value
  )
EXEC(
  'select distinct ' + @Column_Name + ' from ' 
                     + @Table_Name + ' where ' + @Column_Name + ' = ' 
                     + @Search_Value
)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #result WHERE search_value = @search_value)

...
```

Comment: Thanks, Mat! will try to make use of your recommendations!

Comment: Thanks again, with your hint on INSERTing got it working

Answer (score 0):

```
{USE PROD
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #source_table 
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #result_table 
GO
CREATE TABLE #result_table (Table_Name nvarchar(max),Column_Name nvarchar(max),Searched_Value uniqueidentifier)
DECLARE @CURSOR             CURSOR
DECLARE @Table_Name         nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Column_Name        nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Search_Value       nvarchar(max) = concat('''','ABBDFFEA-4576-4AA9-854E-A016433C54F0','''')
SET @CURSOR  = CURSOR SCROLL
    FOR
    (
        select s.TABLE_NAME, s.COLUMN_NAME 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS s
        where s.DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'
    )
OPEN @CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM @CURSOR INTO @Table_Name, @Column_Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #result_table (Table_Name, Column_Name, Searched_Value) EXEC('select distinct ' + ''''+ @Table_Name + '''' + ' AS Table_Name , ' + ''''+ @Column_Name + '''' + ' AS Column_Name , ' + '[' + @Column_Name + ']' + ' from ' + '[' + @Table_Name + ']' + ' where ' + '[' + @Column_Name + ']' + ' = ' + @Search_Value)
FETCH NEXT FROM @CURSOR INTO @Table_Name, @Column_Name
END
CLOSE @CURSOR
--results
SELECT * FROM #result_table}
```