# Update an existing table based on result of executing a variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for some views on how to go about resolving this challenge. I have a variable say `@Var1` which holds a SQL statement within it.

Example

```
@Var1 = `SELECT * from another_table WHERE City IS NOT NULL AND Address IS NOT NULL`
```

When I execute this variable

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Var1
```

I get the desired result, City and Address excluding NULL values.

I am hoping to update a existing table (tbl1) based on execution result of `@Var1`:

Something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE tbl1 AS (EXECUTE sp_executesql @Var1)
```

Is something like this even possible? Or what approach can I take to get the result of `@Var1` into `tbl1`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"update a existing table based on execution result"* what do you mean with this statement? You need joins to update against another result set.

Comment: as @EzLo writes. Then you need to join you result from var1 to your update table otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: I am hoping to update an existing table example:(tbl1) based on execution result of @Var1 as explained in my question.

Comment: @Gary you are basically saying "I want to update [Table A] based on [Table B]".  That is not enough information.

Comment: @JasonGeiger What ever data I retrieve by executing Var1, I am hoping to store that into exiting table "tbl1" . Just wondering if this is a possibility or not possible within SQL?

Comment: IT is possible. But you still need to join that result set onto your table. You could store your var1 result into a temp table and then join it to your tbl1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies for including links for each step but they deserve the credit.

There are 2 steps.  Insert into a temp-table then merge the data from that temp-table into your final table.

You will have to insert into a Temp Table first. 
[INSERT INTO @TABLE EXEC @query with SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622940/insert-into-table-exec-query-with-sql-server-2000)

Then you have to merge that data into you main table.
[SQL MERGE statement to update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806768/sql-merge-statement-to-update-data)

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer, I would adapt this approach.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
UPDATE  tbl1 
        SET Column1= b.Column1,
        SET Column2= b.Column2,
        SET Column3= b.Column3,
FROM    tbl1 a 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  Column1,Column2,Column3
FROM    another_table WHERE City IS NOT NULL AND Address IS NOT NULL ) b ON   a.city_Id  = b.city_Id
```