# My store procedure only executes my first select statement while I wrote three?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InfoTable] 
(
    [Id]               INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeSpanColumn]   NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [TimeStampColumn]  DATETIME     NULL,
    [TimeStringColumn] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [TotalSecColumn]   NVARCHAR(50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

I want to select time`spans` between 2 given dates and substring them to another table like this:

```
 Col1    Col2      col3
 [hh]  |  [mm]  |  [ss]
 ----------------------
 02       55       36
 54       32       41
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sumBetweenDates
    @QueryFromDate DateTime,
    @QueryToDate DateTime
AS
    SELECT 
        SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) as hh
    FROM 
        InfoTable 
    WHERE
        TimeStampColumn BETWEEN @QueryFromDate AND @QueryToDate
    GROUP BY 
        TimeStampColumn

    SELECT 
        SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) AS mm
    FROM 
        InfoTable 
    WHERE
        TimeStampColumn BETWEEN @QueryFromDate AND @QueryToDate
    GROUP BY 
        TimeStampColumn

    SELECT 
        SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) AS ss
    FROM 
        InfoTable 
    WHERE
        TimeStampColumn BETWEEN @QueryFromDate AND @QueryToDate
    GROUP BY 
        TimeStampColumn
```

It only returns the result of first query. For example:

```
[hh]
02
54
```

How can I manage to do what I said?

I can't assign a variable to those select statements cause they may have more than one value after that they are grouped by `timestampcolumn`

Comment: How have you determined that it's only returning one result set? Are you using Management Studio to execute the procedure or some other client?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I simply executed the store procedure in my c# program and filled my datagridview with the results it only showed one column.

Comment: What are you trying to sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your stated desired result, I think you just want a single `SELECT` with all 3 aggregates:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) as hh,
  SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) as mm,
  SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) as ss
FROM InfoTable 
where TimeStampColumn between @QueryFromDate and @QueryToDate
GROUP BY TimeStampColumn
```

But re your comment:

> I simply executed the store procedure in my c# program and filled my datagridview with the results it only showed one column.

If you have *multiple* `SELECT` statements, you have to pay extra attention to how you read them. If you're using a `SqlDataReader` there's the [`NextResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=netframework-4.7.2) method for advancing from one result set to the next. If using some form of data adapter or similar, you need to pay attention to how it describes how to consume multiple result sets. E.g. you'd be looking for stuff to populate a `DataSet`, nor a `DataTable`.

Comment: yes this what I wanted. and how can I have the same results but with inserting into a new table or the InfoTable?

Comment: @absolute455 - `INSERT` has a number of different variants. You're probably familiar with `INSERT (...) VALUES (...)` and StepUp's answer shows `INSERT (...) EXEC`. But there's also `INSERT (...) SELECT ...`. But avoid creating temp tables because you're breaking up a logical query into multiple chunks. Instead use subqueries/CTEs to write a single query that expresses the *entire* task to be accomplished.

Comment: thank you for your advice but cant get its meaning. what do you mean by `temp tables`? I know the meaning of logic behind a code but I dont get your defenition of `breaking a logical query into multiple chuncks` I also dont know `CTEs` and the meaning of your last sentence `exoressing an entire task`.

Comment: when I write this code: `Insert into InfoTable(hh,mm,ss) select SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))),
                     SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))),
                   SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2)))
FROM InfoTable
where TimeStampColumn between @QueryFromDate and @QueryToDate
GROUP BY TimeStampColumn`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate data between columns, then just create a temp table to store results from stored procedure and calculate the desired value.

Let me show an example.

1. Create a stored procedure

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE sumBetweenDates
   @QueryFromDate DateTime,
   @QueryToDate DateTime
   AS

   SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 
       12)) AS X(a, a1, a2)
   /*
   --Insert your query here instead of above test values.
   SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) as hh,
       SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) as mm,
       SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) as ss
   FROM InfoTable 
   WHERE TimeStampColumn between @QueryFromDate and @QueryToDate
   GROUP BY TimeStampColumn
   */
   ```
2. Create a table variable to store result of your stored procedure, Then insert data from your stored procedure `sumBetweenDates '2018-12-1', '2018-12-1'`. Then in `SELECT` statement you can  do any what you want:

   ```
   Declare @T Table (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 int)
   Insert @T Exec sumBetweenDates '2018-12-1', '2018-12-1'

   SELECT 
     t.col1
   , t.col2
   , t.col3 
   , t.col3 - t.col1 CalculatedColumn
   FROM @T t
   ```

Here is `@T` is a table variable. `Declare @T Table (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 int)`. You can know the difference between them by reading [this cool article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1556/differences-between-sql-server-temporary-tables-and-table-variables/).

[This answer will help to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622940/insert-into-table-exec-query-with-sql-server-2000) how you can use `exec stored procedure` to insert data into table.

[In addition, you can read an MSDN article about INSERT using EXEC statement.](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I cant assign a variable to those select statements cause they may have more than one results after that they are grouped by `timestampcolumn`.

Comment: *"If you want to return data from stored procedure, then you need to use return statement:"* I disagree, you should be using `OUTPUT` parameters, for **scalar** values; for starters you aren't limited to 1 then. For datasets, you can use the `INSERT INTO... EXEC...` syntax.

Comment: @Larnu yeah, you are right, I've seen the problem more precisely and edited my answer.

Comment: would you refference me to link to read about `insert exec`? I cant understand your answer. whats `@t`. I was writing the `sumBetweenDates` so now your using this but I dont have any code in that store procedure what is `sumBetweenDates` actually? if its my store procedure then Its not complete I didnt write it completely I got problems so I came to this website what are you referencing to?

Comment: @absolute455 please, see my updated answer. `CalculatedColumn` is a column which can store your desired results. So you can write your logic for your column.

Comment: Thank you for your immersive answer. you helped me alot. really thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure only consists of the first `SELECT` statement, because you are not using `BEGIN`/`END`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sumBetweenDates (
    @QueryFromDate DateTime,
    @QueryToDate DateTime
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) as hh
    FROM InfoTable 
    WHERE TimeStampColumn between @QueryFromDate and @QueryToDate
    GROUP BY TimeStampColumn;

    SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) as mm
    FROM InfoTable 
    WHERE TimeStampColumn BETWEEN @QueryFromDate and @QueryToDate
    GROUP BY TimeStampColumn;

    SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) as ss
    FROM InfoTable 
    WHERE TimeStampColumn BETWEEN @QueryFromDate and @QueryToDate
    GROUP BY TimeStampColumn;
END;  -- sumBetweenDates
```

I am not exactly sure what you want.  Based on the sample data, you seem to want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sumBetweenDates (
    @QueryFromDate DateTime,
    @QueryToDate DateTime
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) as hh,
           CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) as mm,
           CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) as ss               
    FROM InfoTable 
    WHERE TimeStampColumn BETWEEN @QueryFromDate AND @QueryToDate;
END;
```

However, this doesn't seem particularly useful and one would guess that you want to sum something.

Comment: I don't think you *need* `BEGIN`/`END`. After the `CREATE PROCEDURE` and the remaining bits of "header", the body of the stored procedure is everything remaining in that batch.