# Insert result of EXEC into table parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

In a stored procedure, I have an `EXEC` statement; I want to store its results into a table.

First I create table parameter as:

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE
                    (
                        [Item1] INT, 
                        [Item2] DECIMAL
                    )
```

Then I try to insert values as:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTable 
    EXEC [storedProcedure] @testitem = @testitem
```

My question: is this the right way to do that? Or do I need to use a dynamic query?

Because I read similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622940/insert-into-table-exec-query-with-sql-server-2000) and they suggest to use a dynamic query.

Comment: From the link you provided `this question and answer relate to the 2000 version of SQL Server. In later versions, the restriction on INSERT INTO @table_variable ... EXEC ... were lifted and so it doesn't apply for those later versions.`

Comment: You are using a current version of sql server, so the link is irrelevant. The table variable restriction no longer applies (and has not applied for many years). Short answer - your code is fine though some would argue that you should always specify the column list in a insert statement. Laziness is  not a good habit for a developer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @Sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql='EXEC storedProcedure @testitem = @testitem'
INSERT INTO @MyTable ([Item1], [Item2]) EXEC(@Sql)
SELECT * FROM @MyTable;
```

Asserting the above, I've been just tempted to read further... and found this older thread. I bet, it is helpful to analyze it further. [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table/1228165#1228165)

Comment: As OP's link states, the restriction against table variables was removed long ago (2008 maybe). There is no requirement or actual need (in this case) to use dynamic sql.